# How to add input to a database in netbeans

Tags: java, sql, database, netbeans, addition

I'm trying to add input to a bookings table for a fictitious company in Netbeans.

When the user comes to the bookings page they're prompted to a form where they add some details and click the button leading the details to be added and saved to the bookings table

This is what I've used to create the table

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns = "2" border = "1" cellpadding = "0" cellspacing = "2">
     <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="Fill the form to complete booking"/>
     </f:facet>
           <h:outputText value="Enter your name"/>
           <h:inputText value="#{training4uBean.name}"/>
           <h:outputText value="Enter your phone number"/>
           <h:inputText value="#{training4uBean.phone}"/>
           <f:facet name="footer">
           <h:commandButton id="submitBtn" value="Book" action="#{training4uBean.addBooking}"/>
            </f:facet>
         </h:panelGrid>
       </h:form>
```

and in the bean ive put ....

```
 public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
public Integer getPhone(){
    return phone;
}
public void setPhone(Integer phone){
    this.phone = phone;
}

public void addBooking (){

}
```

}

and I'm lost as to what to put in the bean method addBooking, nothing I have done seems to work!

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: did you google your question?

Comment: Yes but nothing I found worked when I implemented it in mine ..

Comment: what did you implement post those portion of your code. Then post how this is not working and we could help you with a solution pointing what is the problem

Comment: Voted to close: 'nothing I have done seems to work' is not sufficiently detailed. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask